# How to create a delete function for vanillajs todo list app?

Tags: javascript

Good day! I've been trying to figure out how to create a delete function in my todo app. I dont know what to do next and the delete function as well as the eventListener is not correct. I hope you guys can help me. I want to fully understand every small projects that I make. Thank you in advance! :)

```js
const inputBox = document.querySelector('.input')
const addBtn = document.querySelector('.input-button')
const todoMain = document.querySelector('.todo-list')
const deleteBtn = document.querySelector('.delete-button')
const deleteAllBtn = document.querySelector('.clear-all')

//Event listeners 
inputBox.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
    let userInput = inputBox.value;
    if (userInput.trim() != 0) {
    addBtn.classList.add("active")
    } else {
        addBtn.classList.remove("active");
    }
})

addBtn.addEventListener("click", todoAdd);
todoMain.addEventListener("click", todoDelete);

// Functions
function todoAdd(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    const todoLi = document.createElement('li');
    todoLi.innerText = inputBox.value;
    
    const todoDeleteBtn = document.createElement('button');
    todoDeleteBtn.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>`;
    todoDeleteBtn.classList.add('delete-button')
    todoLi.appendChild(todoDeleteBtn);

    todoMain.appendChild(todoLi);
    
    inputBox.value = '';

    addBtn.classList.remove("active");
};

function todoDelete(e){
    const item = e.target;
    if (item.classList[0] === 'delete-button'){
        todoMain.removeChild(todoLi);
    }
}
```

```html
<link crossorigin rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" />
<div class="container">
    <h1>TODO list</h1>
    
    <div class="input-container">
        <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Input Text Here">
        <button class="input-button"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>
    
    <ul class="todo-list">
    </ul>

    <div class="footer">
        <span>You have<span class="pending">0</span>pending task left</span>
        <button class="clear-all">Clear All</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues that might be stopping this from working:

1. Your function `todoDelete` tries to access the variable `todoLi`, which doesn't exist in its scope. You define this inside `todoAdd`, but its scope is limited so you can't access the variable from outside the function.

I suspect what you might want to be doing is passing `item` instead.

2. You attach the event listener that triggers `todoDelete` to your `todoMain` element, which means that `e.target` for the function will always be the `ul` element, not your list element. Your if is then always false so the code never runs.

To fix this, attach the event listener to the `todoDeleteBtn` in your `todoAdd` function instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented it quite simply as an example.

When creating the ToDo item, I add a key for the text and a data attribute for the delete button and an onclick event.

The key is important to have the relation between button and text. First i used `new Date()` but i updated with an random Method.  `(Math.random()+1).toString().split('.')[1];`

For deletAll() you can get the entire Parent Node and set html to an empty string.

```js
const inputBox = document.querySelector('.input')
const addBtn = document.querySelector('.input-button')
const todoMain = document.querySelector('.todo-list')
const deleteBtn = document.querySelector('.delete-button')
const deleteAllBtn = document.querySelector('.clear-all')

//Event listeners 
inputBox.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
    let userInput = inputBox.value;
    if (userInput.trim() != 0) {
    addBtn.classList.add("active")
    } else {
        addBtn.classList.remove("active");
    }
})

addBtn.addEventListener("click", todoAdd);
todoMain.addEventListener("click", todoDelete);

// Functions
function todoAdd(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    const todoLi = document.createElement('li');
    const key =(Math.random()+1).toString().split('.')[1];
    todoLi.innerText = inputBox.value;
    todoLi.setAttribute("id", key);
    
    const todoDeleteBtn = document.createElement('button');
    todoDeleteBtn.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>`;
    todoDeleteBtn.classList.add('delete-button')
    todoDeleteBtn.onclick = function() {
      const _key = this.getAttribute('data-key')
      document.getElementById(_key).remove();
      this.remove()
    }
    todoDeleteBtn.setAttribute("data-key", key);
    todoLi.appendChild(todoDeleteBtn);

    todoMain.appendChild(todoLi);
    
    inputBox.value = '';

    addBtn.classList.remove("active");
};

function todoDelete(e){
    const item = e.target;
    if (item.classList[0] === 'delete-button'){
        todoMain.removeChild(todoLi);
    }
}
```

```html
<link crossorigin rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" />
<div class="container">
    <h1>TODO list</h1>
    
    <div class="input-container">
        <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Input Text Here">
        <button class="input-button"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>
    
    <ul class="todo-list">
    </ul>

    <div class="footer">
        <span>You have<span class="pending">0</span>pending task left</span>
        <button class="clear-all">Clear All</button>
    </div>
</div>
```